# open modal box after angular js ajax success response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular js. How can i open a modal box after ajax success call automatically like alert. Iknow in Jquery how to do it but I don't know in angular I have checked bootstrap angular UI documentation but i have confused to open modal box. Can any give simple solutions.

Comment: Very easy: `make ajax request .then(() => open modal)`. Post real code otherwise it's not constructive to answer theoretical question.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921441/angularjs-open-modal-on-button-click